How to totally uninstall an application?
OS: Windows-11
I try to uninstall the application SmoothScroll to override the register key I typed before. But even if I deleted all the file folder named with or similar to "SmoothScroll" on my computer and reinstall the app, the old register key still kept.
So how to fully uninstall an app(for windows system) under this kind of situation?

Have you tried just deleting the unused registry keys?

It depends on what the application does, and what it leaves behind. Stuff like registration keys could be stored in many different places, so I recommend contacting the developer for how to remove them specifically

Most applications just uninstall DLLs, data files, and executables. They very rarely require the registry.

see https://www.smoothscroll.net/help/ If that is not sufficient, some tools can delete empty (and harmless) Registry keys, e.g., CCleaner.

You're asking as if it were a generic question, but you're actually asking a different, very specific question: How to remove the entered register key of "SmoothScroll". There's no universal "complete removal".

Deleting is not uninstalling. If you used an installer to install the app, you will need to use an installer to uninstall it. The Windows installed apps list is where you can typically trigger an uninstall.

You are asking how to either remove all data related to the application "SmoothScroll", or make it forget the registration key you entered.
There is no universal way to remove all data an application stored with "normal" Windows applications. It entirely depends on what and how and where the application stores its data.
The process of uninstallation is implemented by the publisher, so they may or may not remove any number of files and settings, or optionally offer clearing settings or not.

To uninstall an application, deleting the program files is not enough. Installing an application may do any number of additional things during or after installation, like putting configuration data in a different folder (under your user folder, not within the program folder), or into the Windows registry, which you can't see in the filesystem.
To uninstall:

Open Windows Settings -> Apps -> Installed Apps
Find the application, open the three dots, open uninstall


To specifically remove the stored registration key setting you could use Process Monitor to observe and analyze where it is accessed from, and then remove that. Which only works if it is a simple implementation that you can identify.

Most uninstallers bundled with programs don't completely remove all traces of the program.
For your use case it seems the best solution would be to use a third-party tool such as Bulk Crap Uninstaller (repo) for any uninstalls you do in the future.
This tool has more options to remove leftovers including registry entries. Always take care to perform a registry backup before removing these entries however as it could cause unexpected behaviour.
